# POCO: How to use PartHandler for attachments?

Tags: c++, parsing, poco-libraries

I use

```
MailMessage message;
session.retrieveMessage((*i).id, message);
```

( MailMessage: http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.MailMessage.html )

And *message* contains a MIME email. I want to extract the attachments and text from *message*. As said here http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Net.PartHandler.html , I have to use the class PartHandler, but there is no example and I have no clue how. Can anyone help?

Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Googling arround, I found this: https://gist.github.com/jsolid/3916184 searching for RetrieveMessage() will bring you to the usage of a custom made part handler.

Comment: @Christophe Many thanks! :) I'd found the site but I didn't notice the specific function.